# How to set different responses for the GET requests in Python's unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, http, httpretty

I need to return different desponses depending on the GET parameters via [HTTPretty](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty):

```
@httpretty.activate
def test_multiple_requests():
    httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET, 'https://example.com/data.xml?n=0',
                           body='0')

    httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET, 'https://example.com/data.xml?n=1',
                           body='1')

    r = requests.get('https://example.com/data.xml?n=0')
    print(r.text)

    r = requests.get('https://example.com/data.xml?n=1')
    print(r.text)
```

This code prints the following:

```
1
0
```

Why? I thought that it should be

```
0
1
```

instead.

Comment: What are you looking to test? Are you looking to control what GET should return, so you can test something else?

Comment: Have you tried using [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/). Mock out the GET, make it return the value you expect to continue testing based on those return values.